# How to uniquely identify nsmangedobject with string?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsstring, nsurl, nsmanagedobject

I'm using Core data and region monitoring. The only way to distinguish between monitored regions is with a NSString for identifier. I'd love to use NSManagedObjectID, but I can't get it to work.

What I've tried:

```
NSURL *objURL = [managedObjectID URIRepresentation];
NSError *err;
NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL
                                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                   error:&err];
```

the error I get is:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)
```

Any ideas of a better way? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work, you have `err` and `error`. And where are you doing the log?

Comment: Thanks I'll edit to change that. I wrote this in to give an example of what I'm doing. Otherwise that'd cause a compile error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not get the *contents of* the URI of the `NSManagedObjectID`. `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` tries to load the resource pointed by the URI; it uses appropriate operations depending whether the URI is `http` or `file` or etc. But it doesn't know how to deal with an `NSManagedObjectID` URI, and it's not what you want to do anyway.

Instead, I guess what you want to do is

```
 NSString*identifier=[objURL absoluteString];
```

This gives a string representation of the URL.

I'll add Marcus's comment so that everyone will notice:

> Be aware that the objectID can and does change, especially when a migration occurs. Do not rely on that value to be consistent between one launch of the application and the next.

Comment: Be aware that the objectID can and does change, especially when a migration occurs.  Do not rely on that value to be consistent between one launch of the application and the next.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'll add it so that somebody who reads this entry but not the comments section won't miss it...

Comment: Thanks @Marcus for the heads up. What about the `isTemporary:` method? The apple docs make it seem as if it returns NO you're fine.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/Reference/NSManagedObjectID.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectID/isTemporaryID


I can definitely see that occurring on a migration though.

Comment: Temporary vs. permanent is different than the change during a migration.  Even a permanent ID will change during migration.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra - That's bizarre.  What good is an ID if you can't use it as a reliable identifier?  Yet another dubious Core Data architecture decision.

Comment: `objectID` is designed to be unique and consistent within one life cycle of the application. It is not guaranteed as such across life cycles.  For that you should be creating your own.